# Best Way to get Heart Rate in iOS HealthKit App?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, bluetooth-lowenergy, healthkit

I'm writing an iOS app to display real-time Heart Rate from a BTLE device (the Polar H7).  I've found 2 ways to do this:

1. Using [`CBCentralManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks.html) and bit-twiddling the [Heart Rate Measurement Characteristic](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml) by hand
2. Using HealthKit's [`HKObserverQuery`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKObserverQuery_Class/index.html)

As I see it, there are pros/cons to each approach.

Using `CBCentralManager` enables more control (e.g., you can store the sensor location) and quicker setup (i.e., you can start displaying values immediately).  But, from what I can tell, the BTLE device will **not** be seen by `CBCentralManager` if the BTLE device is already paired with HealthKit.

Using HealthKit appears to be the preferred approach (and is much simpler to implement) but requires an extra trip to the Health app to turn on the "Update Health Data" switch.

Should I implement both?  Has anyone dealt with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't dealt with your issue specifically, but I am working on HealthKit integration as well. Based on what you've outline here, I would go with the HealthKit approach and only that approach unless there's some requirement to really push you do to both. If you do have to implement both, I would probably put some abstraction in there so the controllers don't have to know what the source is.

I'm not sure about the extra trip to the Health app you mention. You can ask for permission to the heart rate data from within your app using [requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:readTypes:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKHealthStore_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/HKHealthStore/requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:readTypes:completion:). Here's a tutorial that has a walk through, in case that helps at all: [HealthKit Tutorial with Swift: Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/86336/ios-8-healthkit-swift-getting-started).